# Crontab script not running

Tags: cron

I have script that will run just fine from the command line by simply using “sudo pdfBackup” however when I added it to sudo crontab –e, it’s not running. 
The script is in my /bin/ directory called “pdfBackup”, inside this script is a simple command

```
#!/bin/bash 
rsync -az ~/files/content/pdf  ~/Dropbox
```

This is what my crontab file looks like

```
*/1 * * * * /bin/pdfBackup
```

I set it up for every minute while I am testing it. I can’t figure out why it’s not working. I have another cron job that runs successfully so I know cron is working.

Thanks in advance.

*Edit - I looked in the the syslog and this but no error or anything?

```
CRON[26774]: (root) CMD (/bin/pdfBackup)
```

Comment: I suspect `~/` doesn't mean what you expect it to mean, when the script is run via root's crontab

Comment: You are right! I corrected the path to /home/user/.... and it is running properly now. Thank you.

Comment: @steeldriver: could you convert that to an answer and leave me a comment so that I can upvote?)  **:-)**

Comment: is this a shell script
pdfBackup.sh?

Answer (score 0):

My issues was that that I wasn't referring to the to and from directories in my script properly.

Since it is being run as root, the home directory is different than my user home directory.

Comment: It's best to use full paths when dealing with `cron`.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. **;-)** You should allow the one that helped you to post an answer first, so that that user gets the rep for helping you. (Rep is all the payment we get for helping you...)

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐq ɹW  sure no problem. It wasn't posted as an answer and I didn't want to leave the question unresolved.

Comment: @dn-ʞɔɐq ɹW: real wizardry there with yr screen name !! How did you manage that ?